# How to delete all files in a directory

Tags: linux, ksh, rm

I don't often use Unix/Linux system but I think something awkward happens to me. I would like to delete all files in the DATA directory in my ksh.

```
rm -f $P_VAR/DIR/DATA/*
```

using this in unix environment seems to work but when I run the ksh it deletes the DATA directory.

What is wrong?

Comment: What do `type rm`, `echo rm -f $P_VAR/DIR/DATA/*`, `typeset -p FIGNORE` output?

Comment: Is  `$P_VAR/DIR/DATA/*` possibly a symlink to its parent directory (`$P_VAR/DIR`), in which case `$P_VAR/DIR/DATA` would also be `$P_VAR/DIR/DATA/DATA`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `rm -rf $P_VAR/DIR/DATA/ && mkdir $P_VAR/DIR/DATA` if the `DATA` folder isn't made.

Comment: No.. I could not do that because I would like to know why the DATA directory is deleted. But adding the r argument seems to solve the problem.

Comment: the `-r` stands for 'recursive', so I guess if the * file is a file, it will be deleted, but if it is a folder, the `rm -rf` command will execute on that particular folder

Comment: There are no folders in DATA : the problem is that DATA is deleted